# Firebase .NET SDK how to validate user with email and password Web API

Tags: asp.net, firebase-authentication

I have configured the Firebase Admin, but I do not see an option to check on login if a user entered valid credentials. I was able to create a user by calling `FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateUserAsync()`.

Through the same `DefaultInstance` there are no options to check whether the email and password correspond to an account. How could I do that?

The configuration in `Program.cs`:

```cs
FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions
{
    Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("firebase.json"),
});
```

I also checked the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/auth/firebase-auth) but could not come to a conclusion.

This is my first time trying to use an auth service and do not understand if there is no option or I am just missing something...

Comment: Thats because server with admin firebase sdk has nothing to do with checking email and password. That should happen on Firebase servers. Client sends creds `directly` to firebase servers, firebase checks everything and returns a token to the client. Firebase Admin SDK you are using is for administrative actions like fetching user data or changing a user's email without their existing password. But you can utilize the `token` from authorized user to load his data from firebase. Just dont foreget to `verify` this token at first on your server side.

Comment: So basically I have no option to check whether credentials were right from the backend? Configuring firebase on the frontend with API key intoduces vulnerabilities

Comment: Depends on what are you going to achieve, what is your flow/architecture. I dont really know what are you doing and what was your plan. And no, firebase frontend keys purpose is to stay on frontend and to be available to anyone. Firebase admin sdk keys - nope, secret, only for your backend.

Comment: Firebase does not support username & password authentication. I wanted to store username email in my DB and when a user enters a username I just do a query to get the corresponding email to log in. So I would need to set up Firebase on the frontend and simply authenticate from there. Now what happens if I send requests to the backend? That's where the SDK comes in to validate the token in order to let the user access resources?

Comment: Well yes, but if you really need to use usernames - you can play around the [custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) but I wont recommend doing that, that is a complex task and will bring vulnerabilities..
Token and security - you can configure rules for Firestore, Storage, etc. You can assign custom claims for your users (role= admin, user, etc). Here is some [old docs](https://blog.markvincze.com/secure-an-asp-net-core-api-with-firebase/). With that token you can load user from database and check his claims, permissions, etc with Firebase Admin SDK.